# Shaving or getting a haircut at night

Tags: hair, evening-night, shaving, haircuts

A friend once told me that it's preferable to avoid shaving or getting a haircut at night.

Is there actually anything to this (ie reason/ source etc) and should it be observed, or is it a
*[bubbe meise](https://www.yourdictionary.com/bubbe-meise)*?

Comment: It could be he heard that one should not get a haircut on motzei shabbos,because it's not kavod to shabbas since one should have done it on erev shabboz,but this is not halacha ,just a sensitivity issue,halachicly there isn't anything wrong with getting a haircut at night

Comment: perhaps some kabbalah sprinkled in there @sam (but I am none the wiser)

Answer (score 2):

Kaf Hachaim ([493:28](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.493.28.1?vhe=Kaf_Hachayim,_Orach_Chayim_vol._V-VIII,_Jerusalem_1910-1933&lang=he&with=Shulchan%20Arukh,%20Orach%20Chayim&lang2=he)) presents a discussion in the context of cutting hair on Lag Baomer. He does present a stringent opinion which forbids it all year round, and certainly during the days of Sefirah. He grapples with the same question earlier as well (ibid. 18).

> כח) שם. בהגה. ואין אומרים בו תחנון. גם בערב של יום ל"ב וכ"כ במנהגים בדין התחנון שכן נוהגין במעהרי"ן ובפיה"ם. ובדרשות מהרי"ל כתב המנהג באשכנז שבשחרית א"א תחנה משא"כ בערב אומרים תחנה וא"כ מ"ש הרב ג"כ דאין להסתפר עד ל"ג עצמו הוא ממהרי"ל ע"פ מנהגו אבל לאותן הנוהגין שלא לומר תחנה מבערב ה"ה דמותר להסתפר דהא בהא תליא. וכה"ג כתב המי"ט. ח"י או' ו'. מיהו המחה"ש סק"ג כתב דאף לנוהגין שלא לומר תחנה מבערב אין להסתפר בלילה עו"ש. אבל הר"ז או' ה' כתב כדברי ח"י דלנוהגין שלא לומר תחנון במנחה של ערב ל"ג מותרים ג"כ להסתפר ולישא בליל ל"ג יעו"ש. **ומיהו עיין בס' מל"ח סי' ו' או' ז' שכתב טעם אחר שאין להסתפר בלילה משום שהם ימי דין ואפי' באשמורת כל שלא האיר היום לא טוב להסתפר בכל ימות השנה כ"ש בימי העומר**. ועיין לקמן או' ל' ולעיל סי' רנ"ב או' ט"ו.

Comment: really see the discusion surrounging that siman in turshulchanaruch

Comment: Will do- thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Alex thanks. as long as you don't start correcting the spelling in my comments..

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I wish there was such an option.